# How to optimize this JOIN query that relies on date value?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have the following large query which basically groups transactions by dates using a left join on a date table.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dim.date_value, '%b %e') AS DATE, 
IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(s.amount), 2), 0) AS revenue 
FROM dim_date AS dim  
LEFT JOIN transactions AS s 
ON dim.date_value = DATE(s.date) AND s.user_id = 2807 AND s.status = 'COMPLETED' 
WHERE dim.date_value > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY  
AND dim.date_value < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
GROUP BY dim.year, dim.date_value 
ORDER BY dim.date_value
```

Since my transaction table has got very large, this query has got a lot slower and I am trying to figure out how to **optimize** it?

**Update:**

Explain statement for the above query:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  dim ALL \N  \N  \N  \N  2907    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  s   ALL \N  \N  \N  \N  118871
```

[Schema for dim_date table](http://pastebin.com/Dq2XkS8m).

[Schema for transactions table](http://pastebin.com/iJ6KhvVj).

Comment: indexes? schema? storage type? EXPLAIN plan?

Comment: Please try using [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) on the query and, if you can't read the result, add it to your question :)

Comment: If this same query earlier ran faster than now; then it may not be the issue with this query rather probably with the statistics of table. if you have recently done huge DML on the table; try updating stats of the table.

Comment: I have no indexes on the table. I have updated my question with explain statements. Will also add schema.

Comment: @Rahul I am not strong in this subject by I ran `ANALYZE TABLE transactions` and it showed status as OK. Is this what you were referring to?

Comment: @Abs,I mean `OPTIMIZE TABLE`. Just run `OPTIMIZE TABLE transactions` and see what result you get.

Comment: @Rahul I just did that and I get `Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead` then on the next line a status of `OK`.

Comment: Adding an index on dim.date_value and s.user_id+s.status should speed things up, however the `dim.date_value = DATE(s.date)` is somewhat problematic in the join. Using calculated values (`DATE(s.date)`) in a join will generally prevent (effective) index use on that part of the query.

Comment: @Abs, how many rows does both table has? can you post some sample row for both table. Need not be actual record; just few sample record. can try myself then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX dim_date_value ON dim_date( date_value );
CREATE INDEX tran_user_id ON transactions( `user_id` );
```

The latter is a must, the former is not as important as the latter, but also can help.

Comment: The former might be the PK of dim_date.  Not sure about MySQL, but in most other db engines that would automatically make it indexed.

Comment: Not surprisingly, added just one index to the transactions table reduced the query from 7 seconds to 0.07 seconds. Thanks. I will start to normalize my tables and start adding appropriate indexes as I do not use indexes at all.

Comment: Just remember that while indexes speed up database reads, they slow down database writes.

Answer (score 0):

A likely culprit is this:

```
ON dim.date_value = DATE(s.date)
```

Specifically, it's the function.  If none of your transaction elements contain time elements in the date field, you can join without using the function.  If they do, it might be worthwhile to add a date only field to your transactions table, and put an index on it.